# Insert elements to a map listing the nodes

Tags: ros, c++, diagnostics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am subscribing to `/diagnostics` topic, to which all my nodes are publishing their outputs. In my source file, I have created a map of all the node names as follows -

```
std::map<string, int> TextCode;
TextCode = {{"Camera_node1", 1}, {"LIDAR_node2", 2}};
```

I have prepopulated the map with few nodes (as above). I have a callback function, in which I publish the node name whenever the level of operation is `ERROR` -

```
void diagnosticCallback(const diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticArrayPtr &diags_msg)
{
  int Maincode;
  if (diags_msg->status[0].level == diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticStatus::ERROR)
  {
    Maincode = TextCode[diags_msg->status[0].name];
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Error occured : " << Maincode);
  }
  else if (diags_msg->status[0].level == diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticStatus::OK)
  {
    Maincode = TextCode[diags_msg->status[0].name];
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("No error");
  }
}
```

I want to check the node names every time we receive `ERROR` and then check all the elements of my map `TextCode`, if the name is present. If not then add the name as the next element in the map. How should I proceed with that?

Note - Diagnostics_msgs - http://docs.ros.org/api/diagnostic_msgs/html/msg/DiagnosticStatus.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277311/insert-elements-to-a-map-listing-the-nodes/) by [robo_ninja](https://answers.ros.org/users/27502/robo_ninja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2017-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not really a ROS related question... This is about regular programming...

So, if you receive `ERROR` you want to check if there is already an error stored in the map, and if not, add it?
You can use the Standard `std::map` functions:

- `count` to check if this element is already in the map http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/count/
- `find` to find it http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/
- `insert` to add a new one http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1